# マイナス投票した投稿が編集されたことを知る方法

Tags: サポート, 投票の仕方

投票結果が -4 になっていた[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/42560/19110)が編集され、どちらかというとプラス投票されそうなものに変わっているのを発見しました。しかし既にマイナスがそれなりに入っており、これがプラスになるのは大変そうだなと感じます。スタック・オーバーフローの「良い回答を目立たせる」という原則から言えば、編集された後の回答にはプラス投票が集まってもらいたい所です。

しかし立場を逆に考えてみると、今まで自分がマイナス投票した投稿がその後編集されたかどうかなんて確認していないことに気づきました。

そこで質問です。自分がマイナス投票した投稿が編集されたことを知る方法はありませんか？　多少面倒くさくても良いです。マイナス票を受けて改善された質問に対し、新しく投票をどうするか考えるきっかけが欲しいです。

Comment: 今日の質問( https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/42565/ )でも同じことを感じました。一時的な「熱」でマイナスが集まった後、是正されてもマイナスのままでは良い質問が浮かばれないな、、と。

Comment: マイナス票投票時にコメントでも指摘して、修正後にコメントで返信頂くとか（小声）……と考えて、実際2票目以降の方には意味無いなと

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2020年3月に [投稿をフォローする](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3297) 機能が追加されました。

フォローした質問や回答に編集等があった場合、ヘッダーの受信箱に通知が届くようになりますので、「マイナス票を入れたけど、投稿が改善されれば票の見直しをするつもり」といった場合には、この機能が役立つでしょう。

Answer (score 8):

完璧に求めるものができた訳ではありませんが、Data Explorer を使って「誰かが down-vote した後に編集された投稿の一覧」を見ることができました。[このリンク](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/828909/posts-edited-after-down-vote)から閲覧できます。

Data Explorer は毎週月曜日にしか更新されないので、一時的な炎上を是正したいという用途にはあまり向いていませんが、今回の要求には部分的に答えられたのではないかと思います。

なお Data Explorer の `Votes` テーブルの up/down-vote には `UserId` が紐付いていないため、自分が行った投票のみに制限することはできません。

Answer (score 1):

マイナス投票をした個人が覚えておく。
　→人の記憶は曖昧なので、必ずしも覚えているとは限らない。没
　
　誰かがコメントをつけて編集されたことを知らせる。
　→必ず行われるとは限らないし、マイナス投票をつけた人がそれを見るとも限らない。没
　
　メタ投稿に、現在マイナス投票をつけられている質問と回答という形でリストアップを載せておく。
　→これなら、日ごろ見る人たちが集まり確認と検索が行われやすい。そのようなトピック掲示板が出来た事を知れば、たとえ記事が古くなっても探し当てられるのではないかと考えます。ここでも更新されるとトップに上がる？（Ctrl+Fで文字検索）
　　しかし、非常に乱雑なタイミングで書き換えられる可能性のある質問と回答を追跡し、更新していくのは骨が折れる。とくに、なまじプラス投票の中にマイナス投票が混じっていると、判別が紛らわしい。そして誰が管理するのかという問題がある。没
　
　マイナス投票をつけられた人が、編集が行われたこと、ほかに、質問・解答を閲覧することを要求する。
　→　どこへ？メタ？閲覧版が嵩む。没　すぐに削除させればよい？
　
　マイナス投票をつける前に、再編集を促すのが一番親切だと思います。
　→　でもやっぱりそうするとは限らない。　没

結局その投票者の意識だと思いますが、そうでなければ、システム的にそうした機能をつけていただくしかないのではないかなとも思います。例えば、うろ覚えなんですが、自分の質問に回答がついた場合、マイページの中に、赤い文字でこの回答に対する返事？承認？を検討されましたか？というメッセージが出ます。そうした要領で、過去にマイナス投票したものをストックして列挙させ、この質問及び回答のマイナス投票の撤回を検討されましたか？等と、再読を促すような機能を付与するべきではないかなと考えます。もちろん他ユーザーから見えたら恨み？を買うかもしれないので、見えないようにしていただいた方がいいのかなとも考えますが、今回の質問は何やらマイナス投票が不自然に多い気がして、悪質なにおいがしたので、微妙なところです。
　
　私がこう言えば機能が追加されるのでしたら楽ですが、システム機能追加要求ってどれほど実現されるものなのでしょうかわからないので、希望的な意見にとどめます。

Comment: スタックオーバーフロー(日本語版) のシステムは、基本的にその他 stackexchange のサイトと共通です。システムの text snippet を https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja で翻訳していって、現行のシステムになるのだと理解しています。私の知る限りでは、独自の表示方法( japanese.SE のふりがな表記など)をいじる、ぐらいはサイトごとにカスタマイズされているのは知っていますが、それ以上はちょっと聞いたことがないな、、と思っている状態です。

Answer (score 1):

「マイナス票が一定数入ったものや、いったんクローズされた質問・回答」が「編集」された場合に、システム側でレビューとして汲み取る仕組みがあるのが理想かなと思います。
現状だと票をどちらかに入れた後、投稿が編集されないと取り消しが出来なかった気がします。

Comment: クローズされた質問については、編集があれば再オープンのレビュー・キューに載ります。

Comment: 手動で「再オープン」に票を入れた場合にレビュー・キューに載るのかなと思っていたのですが、クローズ質問が編集されると自動でキューに載るということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。より正確には、[クローズから5日間以内に編集があった場合レビュー・キューに載ります](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/341401)。