# コミュニティによってトップへ挙げられた質問に回答した場合、ユーザーがもう現れそうもない場合

Tags: 討議, サポート, 機能の要求

コミュニティがトップに挙げた質問で、放置されたと思われる質問に、評価や回答がついているもののうち、自動的にベストアンサーが選ばれ、承認されるという仕組みはありませんか？（ないですよね。）

もし、質問放置者の問題をコミュニティ全体で解決するとしたら、いいアイディアと思われますか？　
　
　
　以前[マイナス投票した投稿が編集されたことを知る方法](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2664/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%82%B9%E6%8A%95%E7%A5%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%8C%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/2665#2665)という質問で、システム追加要求というのが難しそうだという事を学んだのですが、それでもあえて、こうした事を提案しておきたいかなと思います。

**質問放置者とは：**
　現実的な世界で死亡や障害の発生、サイト内のトラブルなど何らかの理由によりログインをせず、質問に回答が寄せられているのに応答できない者。
　マルチポストで別サイトの回答を得て、ログインする能力はあるもののここに長期的な期間訪れる気配を感じないものや、ログインはしてもその質問へは応答する気がないと思われるもの。
　質問者の地位を放棄することを宣言したもの。
　
　もちろん、満足した回答が得られていないという意味で質問を放置するのは問題ありません。
　逆にいえば、それ以外の質問と言えるんじゃないかなと思います。

**5W1H(いつ、どこで、何を、どれ、なぜ、どうやって？）**
どこで？日本製SOF,Stack Exchangeで管理されているから本家を含むSOF全体？

1. 長い事ユーザーが現れない場合でその質問に（プラス）評価や回答が付けられている時。
2. 質問放置者の質問とみられる質問。
3. その後、他のユーザーがその質問と同じ質問を出し、再び回答や評価を受け付ける。
4. この際、質問への信用度は元のユーザーのものになる。あるいは、代替者のユーザーへ。
5. コミュニティorシステムは他のユーザーによって代替されたことを元のユーザーに伝える。ユーザーにポイントが入るとした時は、ユーザーが戻って来た時に、ポイントの返還を要求できる。
6. しかし、代替者の苦労をねぎらう意向で、代替した者に一定の信用度を与えることが出来る。
7. クローズ理由?のような機能の一つとして組み込む。

**いいところ**
 1. マルチポストで放っておかれた問題も、アクティブなユーザーの監視下に置くことが出来る。
 2. 長らく放置された質問に回答したユーザーを保護できる。
 3. 白より緑色が好きだ。
 4. 解決したということでコミュニティ的にスッキリする。
 5. 形骸的な未解決質問を消去できる。
 6. 表面的な解決率が上がり、サイトの信用性も高まる。
 7. 例えば、ユーザーが実は死亡していた場合など、永久に再来が見込めない場合も対処できる。
 8. 代替者にとってもいいメリットがある。
 9. 質問者は最終的に疑問を解消したいわけで信用度等を得たいわけではないから、誰が質問してくれてもいいはず？
 10. 安心して回答できるし、信用度や承認ももらえてハッピーです。

マルチポストを嫌う方も多いようですが、私もどちらかと言えば嫌いなほうです。マルチポストが嫌いな理由は回答者の苦労が報われない事と、放置質問が増えることです。自分がそういう扱いをされたからこのような提案をしているのではなくて、まぁそれもあるにはあるのですが、他の人達の回答などが放っておかれている現状もどうにかできないかなと考えました。
　
他の案としては、**承認の合議制的機能**をつけるのもいいのではないかと考えます。
承認が5票集まれば承認扱いとか。
**悪いところ**

1. そんなシステムにするのにどれだけ大変だと思っているのか？（→そこを何とか。）
2. 質問者の主体性が薄まってしまう。質問者が疑問を解消できたわけではない。（権利の上に眠る者保護に値せずといいます。さすがに放置しているのだから、質問者自体その質問をここに残したことへの関心をそれほど持っていないとみなしてもいい。コミュニティ全体へ質問を委譲したと意思を擬制することもできない話ではない。）
3. どれだけの期間放置されていたらそうしますか？（→一年間？2か月くらいが希望）
4. 信用度はどれだけ付与しますか？（→1~5ポイントがいいかも）
5. 結局絵にかいた餅なんじゃないですか？（→そこは何とも・・・。）
6. 複数の回答がついている場合で、信用度が同じときは？（→お礼システムに準じる）
7. 仮に実現できたとして、質問者でもないものが、自分の疑問が解決したなんて言えるのか？
   　（→たとえ承認が来たとしても、別回答を制限するというわけでもなく、そちらの方がいい場合は、そちらへ切り替えられるようにすればいいと思います。回答者が着いた場合に限るので、それ以外はBotさんに任せておけばいいと思います。)

   提案は完全なものではない可能性があります。矛盾しているところもあるかもしれません。が、元のユーザーさんの利益に配慮した状態で、コミュニティの健全性に貢献する結果となることを望みます。
   　場合によっては長期メンテナンスとかにもなるかもしれないので、あまり期待はしていませんが、多分いろんな人がそうして欲しいと思っているんじゃないかなと思って、挙げておきたいかなと思いました。

Answer (score 7):

私は変更の必要性を感じません。

そもそもの話として、スタック・オーバーフローのシステムは回答の承認をそこまで重要視していません。回答が承認されることは、質問者が納得したという程度の意味だと思うのが良いと思います。そして、質問者が納得した回答が常にベスト・アンサーとは限りません。

現在のシステムでは、回答のどれかが正の投票数を得ていれば、質問が「未回答」としてマークされなくなります。また、投票数が多い回答は承認された回答よりも上に配置されます。

**回答が不当に放置されているならば、投票しましょう。** コミュニティによる投票によって、実質的に「承認」されている回答が選ばれます。これは Haru さんが提案なさっている承認者の移譲システムや合議制承認システムを意味的にある程度内包しているので、私はこの変更の必要性を感じません。

Comment: 承認はあくまでも質問者から見た納得程度の意味しかない。SOFは承認システム自体はあまり重要視していない。それよりも実質的にいい回答が上に行き、良くない回答が下に行く、この選別をしっかりすることが、SOFにとってもユーザーにとっても総合的に良い結果であるということですね。それができるのが投票であるということ。まさに的を得ているように感じます。承認は質問者の妥協でなされる可能性も０ではありませんし、回答が必ず正しくなくとも出来る話ですからね。

Answer (score 4):

[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)のページにも解説がありますが、「承認」はあくまで「**回答者にとって役に立ったか**」の目安に過ぎないので、第三者が代わりに承認することにはあまり意味を見い出せません。
(たとえ質問者からの承認が付かなくても、誰かの役に立つ情報はあるはずです）

「回答者にとって役に立ったか」の基準も結局は主観でしかなく、回答を理解しているというよりは書かれた内容をコピペで実行できたか、で選ばれているようなケースもたまにあります。

**回答者の労をねぎらうなら投票しましょう。**

---

回答の放置やそれの原因の1つとなるマルチポストも結局は「マナー(ネチケット)」の範疇でしかなく、徹底してもらうのも中々難しいでしょう。「未承認の質問が多数残っている場合は、新規質問を制限する」などのアプローチも考えられますが、未承認質問をどうするかとは別の視点の話になるかなと思います。

Comment: nekketsuuuさんと同じく投票せよということですね。おっしゃっている事は別の角度や表現でなさっているように感じました。確かに煙草の受動喫煙や飼犬の落とし物処理等、マナーが徹底できれば今の時代は全て治っているはずですからね。お二人の意見を聞きますとSOFのためというより、「私がそうしたかった」というのが正体ですね。

Answer (score -1):

他の方たちの意見が見られないので、言い出しっぺの私が賛成派の意見を言います。
お二人の意見を受けた上での回答です。お二人の意見が無ければ書けませんでした。
お二人の意見をまとめると、
　
　**承認は、質問者にとって、回答に納得したという程度の意味。

　必ずしも質問者が回答に納得していない場合でもなされることがある。

　いずれにせよ、主観的なものであり、コミュニティはあまり重視していない。

　それよりは投票によって、実質的にいい回答と悪い回答を秩序立てた方がいい。

　機能を追加する苦労も多い。（これは私）**

と言ったことだと思います。

---

**回答は質問者にとって「点」である。**
　　必要ではないという事は、絶対つけちゃいけないという事ではないと思います。
　そして、承認にそこまでの意味がない以上、やはり私の意見に賛成し、他者が質問を承認したと　しても、それはそれでいいということではないでしょうか？
　たとえ、質問者が承認しようと、承認しまいと、質問者にとっては、自分の疑問が解決したかど　うかが、最大の問題です。
　そして、解決すれば、質問者はもうそれを現実的に自前のコード等に組み込み、自身の創造物を　前進させていきます。また、それで充分なはずです。（ＳＯＦはユーザーの開発の手段の場であって、目的の場所ではないと思うからです。）
　質問者にとって、回答は、自分の疑問を解決してくれるかどうかという意味で、「点」の問題で　あると言えます。
　たとえ適当な答えでも、質問者の疑問を解決してくれれば、十分な時もあります。
　質問者によっては、回答者にお礼の意味も込めて、疑問が解決していないのにも関わらず承認をすることがあります。そうした、質問者の主観が大きく作用する「承認」でありますから、限定的に他者がそれを代わりに行えるとしても、何ら問題はないのではないかと考えます。
　何も、出たばかりの質問を別の人間が承認ボタンを押せるというわけではなく、上に書いたよう　に限定的な条件の下で出すのですから、問題はなかろうと考えるのです。
　**されど回答は残る。コミュニティにとっては「線」の問題**
　質問者にとって、回答は自身の疑問を解決すればＯＫだと言いました。そしてそれは私の勝手な決めつけではないと考えています。もしその疑問の解決法を忘れれば、またそのサイトを訪れればいい話だし、自分のコードを見返せば済む話です。（その際、前よりいい回答があれば、素敵ではないですか？）もしその二つともがどこに行ったのかわからなければ、再度質問を出すのもいいでしょう。しかしこれらはあまりみられる行動ではありません。
　↑で述べたように、質問者は、自分の疑問が解決したら、それ以上はあまり回答とは関わらないように思います。
　しかし、コミュニティとしてはどうでしょうか？
　その回答は、ずっと残ります。そして、回答は一つとは限りません。
そのため、投票によって、順序付ける必要があると考えます。
　実質的にはいい回答が、上へ行き、悪い回答は下へ行く。承認された回答が、↓へ行くこともある。ならば、なおさら私の意見を受け入れたとしても、問題自体は起きないはずです。
　何より、質問者さえも、自分の疑問点とその解決と合わせた上で、自分で回答を編集する側に回れば、より具体的にわかりやすい回答が書け、さらに、それに順位付けの投票が巡って来るという事にもなり、いい事なのではないでしょうか？回答を書き、それが質問者の疑問を解決するものであるべきならば、自己解答も評価されてしかるべきですよね？しかし、自己承認は信用度がもらえません。これは自己満足承認を防ぐためであることは容易にわかるのですが・・・。のちに語る承認自体の存在意義と相まって、これは問題だと思っています。
　**実は承認制度はいらないのではないか？**
　投票が実質的に役に立つ回答を順序付けるのであれば、どうして承認というものが備わっているのでしょうか？（これは別質問として挙げるのも面白いかもしれません。）
　仮に承認という制度がなくなったとして、全てが投票によって順序付けられるとすれば、今と何か変化はありますか？
　むしろ、**実質と名目が一致**し、いいことづくめではないですか？
　**たとえ承認ボタンがなかったとしても、その中の回答によって、質問者が疑問を解決できればＯＫなはずです。**
　
　人は承認欲求を持ちます。たとえ間違えてたとしても、承認されれば嬉しいことはあります。
　そういう意味で、理屈抜きで、承認制度がなくなるのはさみしいと思います。
　しかし、承認ボタンによって表現しなくても、解決しましたとコメントをいただき、解決しなかった場合は放っておくか、駄目でしたとコメントをはっきりいただく方が、私としては承認を受けたり、信用度をもらうよりもずっと嬉しいし、もやもや感のもなくなります。これが、最低限であってほしいです。これができないのは、マナー？の問題ですが、料理して、飯を作ってもらうが片付けない人のように感じます。質問して、回答を作ってもらうが、最後まで質問者として立つ鳥後を濁さない人のようには思えないのです。

**承認ボタンだと、却ってこの部分がぼかされてしまいます。**
　
　**承認という魔力**
　一度承認がなされた質問には、もう回答をしようと思わなくなりませんか？確かに制度的にはいくらでもできます。しかし、解決した質問ではなく、未解決の質問の内から優先的に回答をつけようと思う方も少なくないと思います。また、１５ポイントが素直に欲しいというのも、強力な動機なのではないでしょうか？未解決の疑問の方が、旨味があるのです。
　回答者としては、質問者の疑問に答えるという事が主な目的であることも多いです。
　解決したならこれ以上言う事は何もないよ。という考えで、ふつうにありうる話だと思います。　
　だけど、質問者が疑問を解決する事が出来、かつ、いい回答が残るようにするには、案外、承認制度はやめた方がいいのかもしれません。

いい回答というのは、最低限、質問者の疑問を解決するに十分な物であるはずであること。
　そして、それ以上に、他者から見てわかりやすいものであるはずです。
　すなわち、回答は、今後コミュニティに半永久的に残る「線」の問題だと考えます。
　逆に、質問者の疑問を解決したとみなされない回答には、あまり投票がされているようにはおもえません。（この承認というマークが、回答者のやる気をそいでいるように思うのです。）
　**私は、この「線」が、「点」によって屈折されているように感じるのですが、気のせいでしょうか？**
　
　
　仮に、
　Ａ～Ｃの答案があるとしましょう。
　Ａ～ＣはＡに１ポイント入り、Ｂ，Ｃは０点。そして、質問者はＡで解決したと言っています。
　しかし、後からＤが、よりいい回答を書こうと意気込み、３ポイントもらえる回答を書くこともできます。　
　また、数か月後、ＥやＦが現れ、よりいい回答を書こうと、ＥやＦの回答を書いたとしましょう。すでにＡの回答の時点で、質問者は満足しています。多くの人は、Ａに１ポイント入って承認されれば、もうＤやＥやＦたらんという気持ちは失うのではないですか？承認とはコミュニティにとって大した意味は持たないとはいえ、回答者にとっては、自分の回答への動機に大きく作用するのではないでしょうか？

こうして、承認をしなくても、投票によって良い回答が決まるとすれば、いくらでも回答をよくして行こうという機運が高まるのではないでしょうか？また、どんなにいい回答を書いても、それ以上は無理だという回答が、研ぎ澄まされていくのではないかと考えます。みんなが見てくれる必要はありますけど、見てほしければ更新という技があります。
　承認は、解決した以上はもうその質問には触れないという心理的効果を持っているように思えます。もちろん何度もいうように、全員が全員そうだと言えませんし、実際、承認後も書き込んだ方がいらっしゃいます。承認によって得られる１５ポイントが、回答者を引き付ける大きな要因であると感じていますし、間違ってはいないのではないでしょうか？（もし質問者が投票してくれれば２５ポイント入るんです。ただ、妥協で承認をした質問者がさらに投票をすることもあるのです。）（なんだか、質問者が自由に選べるボーナスチャンス的な性質にも思えます。）
　
　案外、承認は、心理的にコミュニティに「線」としての回答が残ることを阻害しているのではないかなという気がいたします。

投票を大切だというのはわかりますが、この承認というものが、案外、投票というものの大切さを認識しにくくするストッパーのようなものにしてしまっているのではないですか？**外してしまった方が、投票に眼が行く**と思うのは私だけでしょうか？

また、上で述べた答えですが、マルチポストなどにより、質問が放置された場合にも対処できるように感じます。今まで、ログインしていても、答える気があるのかないのかはっきりしない方もいました。別サイトで同じ回答で承認されていながらも、こちらは放置されているのは、ちょっと個人的にも気持ちが悪かったんです。

こういう社会的コミュニティには、衛星要因というものがあります。
部屋が汚くても仕事はできるし勉強もできる。でも、やっぱりきれいなほうがいいよね？ということであり、必ずその行動を行うために必要なものではありません。逆に仕事や勉強に直接役に立つものを、動機付け要因というようですが、私が求めているのは、コミュニティの衛生環境を良くしようという事と似ています。
　だから、煙草の受動喫煙などをコメントに例としてあげました。あれをしっかりしなかったからと言って、私たちが日ごろ社会生活を送る上では、今のところ支障はないのではないでしょうか？空き缶やゴミがそこらへんに散らばっていても、こうしてプログラミングを打つことはできますからね。
　そのため、必要だ、不必要だ、というよりは、もう少し気持ちよくなれる方法があるのではないかということだと言えます。皆さんの観点から言われてしまうと、確かに、不必要でしょう。ただそもそもそういう性質の問題提起だからです。**気にしなければいい話なのです。**
　ただ、コミュニティを良くするのは、必要なものだけを取り付けるという事ではないとも考えます。また、コミュニティも、コミュニティを気持ちよく利用するために・・・という事で、質問や回答など、ユーザーとしての態度やマナーへも、ヘルプを与えているのですから、気持よく利用・・・に引っ掛けることもできないことではありません。

コミュニティ的にデメリットとしては、問題解決率というものがはっきりとしないという事になります。おそらくは、質問数に、この承認数を割って１００分率をだしているのでしょうけれども、そうしたものをどうするのだ？という疑問も浮上してきます。（これも適当な承認や投票の低い承認がまざっていますから、どれほど信用できるのかということでもありますけどね。）

しかし、コミュニティの衛生要因を掲げ、放置質問者の落とした質問をクリーンにし、さらに回答の精度を上げ、そして投票というものが実質を決定し、さらにコミュニティ全体の眼が投票へと向く。マルチポストや放置質問者にちょっと気分を悪くされる必要もなくなる。どんなに放置された質問でも、いい回答さえ書けばいいからです。ここで、質問者との連絡が取りづらくなるのではないか？という指摘も考えられますが、謂われなくてもちゃんとする質問者はちゃんとしてくれると思います。（解決宣言をしてくれた質問者にむしろ信用度を与えるという手もあるかもしれません。承認ではなく、解決宣言がいいかもしれません。）
　
　そういう意味で、承認を動くか、なくすようにした方が、（一番多い投票者に承認が動くようにでもすれば）良い回答を書こうという事にもなり、一度承認がついたからという事もないし、放置質問者の方をコミュニティ側が放置することが出来、たとえ質問者は承認していない回答から疑問を解決するとしても、それはそれでいいはずです。もうかなり本家の方は今までのやり方で進んでおり、今更感はありますが、言って見たかったので書いてみましたし、現実的にあまりいい思いをされていない方もいらっしゃると思いましたし、コミュニティを良くして行こうとか、投票を大切にしようという気運に会う提案だったのではないかなとは、考えていますので、賛成派がいないということで、ぼっち的な印象はありますが、意見を言ってみる事にしました。
　
　今回の質問と回答がどのようなものであれ、結果として、
　　
　**投票というものの大切さを別の角度から示すことができた**

という意味では、（狙っていたわけではないですが、）成功だったと思います。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: SOはQ&Aサイトであり「質問者の疑問を解決する」のが目的です。そして承認は付いた回答のうち1つに「解決した/納得した/理解した」を"質問者"が意思表示する仕組みです(SO内でも場所によっては"ベストアンサー"という表現になっています)。Haruさんは「投票があるのに承認の仕組みのせいでやる気がそがれる」と考えてるようですが、私は全く逆です。一般的なQ&Aサイトでは複数の回答が付いても「ベストアンサー」を選べるのは1つだけで、その他の回答はある意味浮かばれません。しかしSOでは投票の仕組みによってベストアンサーにならずとも信用度で評価されうる可能性があり、モチベーションに繋がると思っています。