# 受信箱をもっと活用出来ませんか？

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求

最近の競技プログラミング関連のトピックや過去ログを見ていて思いついたのですが

- DownVote, クローズ投票した質問が更新されたとき、Vote/クローズした人の受信箱にその旨通知が来る

ような機能追加は可能なのかな？と思い、質問させて頂きました。

期待されるメリットは、DownVote, クローズ投票された質問が、質問者の工夫やコメントにより、質問の質が上がった際に

- DownVoteやクローズ投票が取り下げられやすくなる
- 結果、質問がクローズされにくくなる。または再オープンされやすくなる
- ひいてはスタックオーバーフローのQ&Aの質の向上に繋がる

です。

例えば、StackExchange全体ではなく、日本だけでもテストケースとして運用して、有効であればExchange全体にフィードバックするというのもありかと思います。

Comment: [https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2664/%e3%83%9e%e3%82%a4%e3%83%8a%e3%82%b9%e6%8a%95%e7%a5%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%8a%95%e7%a8%bf%e3%81%8c%e7%b7%a8%e9%9b%86%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%82%92%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95/2665#2665]　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　マイナス投票した投稿が編集されたことを知る方法で過去に似たような事が話題になりました。私もこれはあった方がいいと思います。受信箱にそのような機能が追加できればいいですね。

Answer (score 3):

Meta Stack Exchange に投稿されていた、関連しそうな質問たちのリストをコミュニティ wiki としてまとめておきます。ただしネットワーク全体における既存の議論をまとめているだけであり、このサイトにおける機能要求を妨げるものではありません。

- [Notify close voters when a closed question gets edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56849/341401)

  - クローズ投票に参加したクローズ済み質問が編集されたら通知してほしいという提案です。
  - [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) になっているので、賛成する方は投票すると良いと思います。
- [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/341401)

  - マイナス投票した投稿が編集されたことが通知されるオプションをつけて欲しいという提案です。
  - [Jeff はコメントの @name 通知で充分だと言っています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52628/341401)が、大量のマイナス投票を受けています。
  - 理由はよく分かりませんが [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) になっています。
- [Should you be notified if something you vote on is edited? Why can you change your vote after something's been edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135626/341401)

  - 投票した投稿が編集されたら通知すべきか？という議論です。
  - そのままだと大量にきて鬱陶しいので「マイナス投票に限る」「元の投稿者が編集した場合に限る」「投稿されてから限られた時間の内の編集に限る」などの提案が為されています。
  - status タグはついていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にします。

Answer (score 0):

賛成です。特にクローズに対しては欲しいです。ただし、そのまま実装するとすごい数の通知が来るユーザーがいそうなので、以下のような制限を設けたいです。

1. オプション機能にする。オフにすることができるようにする。

   - 再オープンを活性化させたいのであって、クローズをやめさせたいわけじゃないからです。
2. 通知が来る頻度を制限する。半日に1回や1日に1回など。

   - 何回も行われた細かい編集が大量の通知を生むことを防ぐ意図もあります。

なお一応現状でも、クローズ票を入れた質問一覧は下のスクリーンショットのように自分のプロフィールページから確認できました。

[image: プロフィールページのメニューを「票」→「クローズ」の順にクリックしたところのスクリーンショットです]

Comment: クローズやDwonVoteをやめさせたいのでは無いというのは僕も同意です。修正したことが評価される仕組みがあると、よりこのサイトの質が上げられないかな？という疑問が出発点です。

Answer (score 0):

「改善待ち」から編集されるとレビューキューに入るはずですが、ヘッダ部分のレビューキューはいったんクリックしてメニューを展開しないと通知があることを確認できません。ここを「受信箱」や「実績」と同じ様に、何か通知がある状態の場合にはアイコンの色を変えたり数字を表示することで気づきやすくなるんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。それでも良さそうですね。けど、DownVoteも同様に通知してくれた方がいいのでは？と思っているので、その辺が迷いどころかなと