# 質問と回答のフォロー機能が追加されました

Tags: 討議

この投稿は、@Yaakov Ellis さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された "[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/314875)" の和訳です。

どうぞご編集くださいませm_ _m

---

**本文**

質問と回答のフォロー機能が（MSEで[以前にアナウンス](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345148/314875)しました通り）Stack Overflow及び全てのStack Exchangeサイトネットワークにて追加されたことをお知らせいたします。（スタック・オーバーフロー多言語版サイトでは翻訳が準備でき次第有効になります。）

投稿のすぐ下のメニューにある[フォロー]ボタン（[共有]ボタンの左横）をクリックすると、質問や回答をフォローできます。

[image: Get updates on questions and answers]

投稿をフォローすると、全ての新しい回答（質問をフォローした場合）、コメント、編集、及びお知らせの通知が届きます。実行したアクションに関する通知は届きません。現時点では、投稿の所有者が受け取った通知や@メンションによる変更は行っていません。

当初は質問のフォローのみを含める予定でしたが、みなさんのおかげで質問と回答の両方を同時にリリースすることができました。PC版とモバイル版の両方で使用が可能です。

今後は、さらに2つの関連するリリースを計画しています。

1. **フォロープロフィールタブと質問リストフィルター**：フォローのタブがユーザープロフィールアクティビティページに追加されます。各ユーザーがフォロー中の質問や回答のリストをタブで表示できるようになります。標準のソートも使用可能で、リストからフォローを解除することも可能になります。ユーザー（モデレーターやスタッフを除く）は、他のユーザーに関するこれらの情報を見ることはできません（API、SEDE、またはデータダンプで公開されることもありません）。更に、質問リストページの[詳細]ドロップダウンのフィルターが`フォロー中`に追加されます。
2. **お気に入り機能の名前を「ブックマーク」に変更**します。この機能はお気に入りと同じですが、ユーザーの期待と使用法をより正確に表すために名前とアイコンが更新されます。また、質問の「ブックマーク」と「フォロー」の両方が可能になります。

この新機能によって、タブを維持しながら気になるコンテンツへのアクセスを改善したいと考えています。